# ldavis produces a jston file, in which the vocabulary contains repeated terms

Tags: r, lda

I applied the command createjson in LDAvis. in the json output, the vector of the vocabulary contains repetitions, which should not be there.
Anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem occurred with a large sample and not with a small reproducible one. That is why I was asking for similar problemsearches rather than a solution.